# Как в питоне запустить параллельно функцию в 2020 году?

Tags: python, многопоточность

хотел бы знать как в 2020году правильно запускать задачу в python3+ параллельно?

Задача имеется ввиду функция, которая будет исполняться на отдельной нити параллельно(т.е. multiprocessing не подходит).

Честно говоря, в интернете кроме как вызвать Thread и запустить его демоном(так я и делаю сейчас), больше ничего толкового не находится. Но кажется мне, что все-таки так делать это слишком ретроградно.
Нагуглил тут pykka, и создание актора примерно так:

```
class Adder(pykka.ThreadingActor):
    def add_one(self, i):
        print(f'{self} is increasing {i}')
        return i + 1
```

Но опять же не хватает квалификации понять: будет ли это выполняться параллельно?
В Python я новичек совсем, помогите... Может это совсем невозможно т.к. GIL и т.д.

Можно свести задачу к следующему: в одном потоке делать кое-что, в другое потоке по таймеру, вызывать еще одну функцию - в ней посылать rpc-запросы:

ПОТОК 1: блокирующая функция

ПОТОК 2: по таймеру вызываем rpc_send()

Comment: multiprocessing очень даже подходит.

Comment: @andreymal, мультипроцессинг это для разных процессов же...

Comment: Ну да, а в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Ну а pykka.ThreadingActor это всё равно обёртка над обычным Thread

Comment: @andreymal, ну как в чем проблема?) проблема в том, что все-таки создавать процесс для вызова функции это ж оверхед такой, нехилый

Comment: @andreymal, есть ли еще такие "обертки"? ну я имею ввиду, какие в 2020 еще обертки используются?

Comment: Во-первых, технически поток это тоже ещё один процесс с общей памятью, так что оверхед тоже такой нехилый. Во-вторых, зачастую ничто не мешает насоздавать процессов/потоков один раз заранее и переиспользовать их в будущем с нулевым оверхедом (такой пул обязательно делают все «взрослые» проекты), а если в вашей задаче переиспользовать процессы/потоки невозможно, то вы делаете что-то очень странное. Ну и в-третьих, если в вашей задаче уже начинает мешаться GIL, то возможно вы выбрали неправильный язык программирования :)

Comment: Выбор метода распараллеливания сильно зависит от того где «затык» (bottleneck). У вас задача “IO bound” или “CPU bound“ ?

Comment: @MaxU, видимо io bound - чисто по таймеру посылать в сеть кое-что

Comment: Возможно вам будет достаточно использовать [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html)

Comment: @MaxU, нет, с http вообще не связана задача

Comment: Для асинхронных приложений и поток не нужен ставишь таймер и он выполнится когда будет свободный луп

Comment: @eri, а можно поподробнее: в смысле таймер? что-то не гуглится ничего подходящего

Comment: Чем более подробнее вы опишите вашу задачу в вопросе тем полезнее будут советы. Это же очевидно! (c) Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: @MaxU, изменил заголовок чуток

Comment: Обычному треду больше 50 лет, так что если нужен тред - он останется тредом. Из модного в 2015-2020 - это запускать io в одном треде асинхронно.

Comment: @xperious для io-задач потоки не нужны прям вообще. Тот же высокопроизводительный веб-сервер nginx умудряется успешно обслуживать тысячи клиентов ровно в одном потоке и одном процессе. Пока идёт ожидание приёма или передачи данных, поток может заниматься другими делами, поэтому одного потока на всех вполне достаточно.

Comment: @xperious кстати, в момент ожидания передачи/приёма данных GIL освобождается, так что даже при использовании обычных потоков этот самый GIL не должен вам мешать.

Answer (score 1):

[call_later](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_later), call_at, call_soon и тд выполняется в основном потоке

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def timer(loop):
    loop.call_later(1, timer, loop)
    print('тыц')

timer(loop) # первый тыц сразу

loop.run_forever()
```

loop.run_forever() - блокирует, так что остальной код надо писать также на тасках asyncio.

В этом примере таймер следующий тыц выполнится через секунду, но после слова `await` в основном коде или при запуске любой операции на `loop`. Если других задач нет - то выполнится по таймеру.

По условиям задачи есть блокирующая функция - лучше переделать её на неблокирующий вариант. Асинкио предоставляет возможности для любого IO сделать асинхронный код.

Если сделать это не удается, то блокирующий кусок выносится в тред

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def blocking_code():
    time.sleep(1000)

def timer(loop):
    loop.call_later(1, timer, loop)
    print('тыц')

timer(loop) # первый тыц сразу
task = loop.create_task(loop.run_in_executor(
    None, blocking_code)) 

loop.run_forever()
```

При этом GIL ещё работает. Обычно это не проблема, но можно его обойти через процессы

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

... loop.run_in_executor(pool, blocking_code) ...
```

P.S. Никогда не выполняйте блокирующий код в основном потоке хотябы потому что "программа не отвечает, завершить процесс?"

Comment: спасибо, а как потом прибить этот run_forever?

Comment: loop.stop() потом loop.close() - но если это нужно, то скорее всего у приложения неправильная архитектура.)

Comment: так как сделать этот самый stop, если функция run_forever блокирующая?)
в другом потоке?

Comment: можно из другого потока, можно из колбэков. но если надо просто таймер остановить - там проще делается